# How to crop text with dynamic width, fluid layout?

Tags: css, crop

How to crop text when the width of element is dynamic?

It's possible to crop text when width of element is fixed:

```
.my-class {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

But how to do it when width is dynamic?

Real example - header of application with the title floating at the left and the toolbar floating at the right:

[image]

The title should take all free place but not more:

[image]

How to crop text in such dynamic title?

Code to play live http://cssdeck.com/labs/fbe2t2qo/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out it's actually possible to do, changes are:

- set the toolbar first in the html and make it floated to the right.
- set text overflow on title.

HTML

```
<div class='header'>
    <div class='header-toolbar'>
        <button>Create</button>
    </div>
    <div class='header-title'>
        Very very very very very long very very very long title
    </div>

    <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header, .header-title, .header-toolbar {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.header-title {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.header-toolbar {
    float: right;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

Code http://cssdeck.com/labs/na24g9nf/0

P.S.

It's not my answer, it was answered by this guy http://www.sql.ru/forum/memberinfo.aspx?mid=114453 in this thread http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=979934

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS `min-width` and `max-width` property, that will do the job for you

```
.my-class {
  min-width: 100px;   <----Here
  max-width: 500px;   <----Here
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: But I don't know `max-width` - tolbar have different width (sometimes one, sometimes many buttons), I don't know how much space is there left for title.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin than use your width as `auto`

Comment: Thanks, but seems it doesn't works with `auto` http://cssdeck.com/labs/nhrs0pwd/0

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin you have to give a certian width, or else whats the use of floating the div to left?

Comment: @mr-alien I just want a header with title in the left and a toolbar in the right. Toolbar may have different amount of buttons, title should take all the free space but no more. I don't know how to do it without float (or tables).

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin `text-overflow: ellipsis;` has nothing to do with this because you've to define width, there's no other way

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use floats then have a look at the following solution with table-cells.

This solution uses 'display: table' in CSS for 100% fluid text-overflow ellipsis.
NO FLOATS needed!

HTML:

```
<div class='header'>
  <div class='header-title'>
     <div class="fluid-ellipsis-container">
        <div class="fluid-ellipsis-content">
          This solution uses 'display: table' in CSS for 100% fluid text-overflow ellipsis. <strong>NO FLOATS needed!</strong> It's important to note that this works because of the browser's process of calculating the 'table-cell' width within a fixed layout scheme of the parent 'table' div, in effect creating a "fixed" table-cell width on each browser reflow/paint, hence applying the ellipsis property without dynamic width issues.
        </div>                    
     </div>      
  </div>
  <div class='header-toolbar'>
    <button>Create</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header, .header-title, .header-toolbar {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.5);
    padding: 5px;
}
.header{
    display: table;
}
.header-title {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 85%;
}
.header-toolbar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.fluid-ellipsis-container{
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.fluid-ellipsis-content{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

It's important to note that this works because of the browser's process of calculating the 'table-cell' width within a fixed layout scheme of the parent 'table' div, in effect creating a "fixed" width on the cell on each browser reflow/paint resize, hence applying the ellipsis property without dynamic width issues.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/j5zk46la